# Woocommerce: disable "add to cart" for expensive product

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm using the Woocommerce plugin to sell a dozen of products. 
One of them is really expensive, and the seller want to hide the "add to cart" button for this specific product and replace it with a "Contact us".

What would be a the right function to add in my theme functions.php in order to hide the "add to cart" button for this product?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be done via php and adding something to `functions.php` but that would be more complicated and difficult than simply using jQuery to hide/remove the "Add to Cart" button on that specific page and replace it with the "contact us" text or link.

Comment: Thanks Ennui. Any idea of the jQuery's piece of code to insert?

Answer (score 0):

The newer version of WooCommerce has this functionality built into it...

[Woo-Themes: Catalog Visibility Options](http://www.woothemes.com/products/catalog-visibility-options/)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks John, but it's not a WooCommerce functionality, it's a proper plugin. I'm sorry but I don't want to pay $49 just to remove the "add to cart" for a single product! I'm sure there's a possibility to insert a function in functions.php, telling which product ID is concerned.